# Transfer weight problem

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I have followed some tutorials but I can't transfer the weight properly. I just got the neck weight. I'm using blender 2.78c.
[image]

Comment: could you add your .blend file on blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to be able to help you

Comment: It's too big, I can't upload it. Where should I upload it ?

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3298" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3298/)

Comment: I don't know about your plans but why don't you use Automatic Weight painting and adjust the weights afterwards? Why do you want to transfer weight? between two meshes or mirroring?